Setting up Google Enhanced Conversion Tracking with React and GA4
I'm trying to setup Enhanced Conversion Tracking as per the instructions here: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/13258081
I am using React-GA4, and have the following code.
For initiatlisation:
ReactGA4.initialize([
    {
        trackingId: 'G-XXXXXXX',
        gaOptions: {
            transport: 'image'
        },
        gtagOptions: {
            allow_enhanced_conversions: true
        }
    }]);

For conversion tracking:

var event = {
    currency: "AUD",
    transaction_id: order.orderId,
    value: order.total,
    shipping: order.shipping,
    items: itemList
}

var userData = {
    "email": order.email,
    "phone_number": order.phoneE164,
    "address": {
        "first_name": address.firstName,
        "last_name": address.lastName,
        "street": address.streetAddress1,
        "city": address.suburb,
        "region": address.state,
        "postal_code": address.postcode,
        "country": address.country
    }
}

ReactGA.gtag('set', 'user_data', userData);

ReactGA.event('purchase', event);

I can see the purchase event correctly fire, however, I'm not able to validate that it's sending the enhanced conversion data, as per these instructions in the page, as there's no network requests matching:


Right-click on your web page.

Select Inspect.

Select the Network tab.

Enter “google” in the search bar.

Find the network request that's going to "googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/" (or "google.com/pagead/1p-conversion/" on some browsers).



Does anyone have any insights into how to get this working?

Where are those testing instructions from? check if you see the "collect" requests in the Network.

@BNazaruk - The testing instructions are from the link I mentioned at the top. And yes, the "collect" requests are being sent through correctly, and I can see the data/conversions in GA4.

seems to me like you're mixing up google ads enhanced measurement and ga4 enhanced measurement.
